# Деструктор производного класса

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, деструктор

Следует ли объявлять деструктор производного класса виртуальным, если в базовом классе он уже помечен таковым? Т.е., необходимость в виртуальном деструкторе в базовом классе мне ясна, в производном - нет. Возможно, не задумывался бы об этом, если бы не натыкался на статьи, в которых даны примеры, где по мнению авторов наличие виртуальных деструкторов в производных классах является, *видимо*, хорошим тоном.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно стандарту C++ (7.1.2 Function speciﬁers)

> 5 The virtual speciﬁer shall be used only in the initial declaration
>   of a non-static class member function;

То есть спецификатор функции `virtual` обязан присутствовать только в первоначальном объявлении функции.

Тем не менее я соглашусь, что присутствие этого спецификатора в объявлениях функций в производных классах делает код более ясным и самодокументируемым.

Что касается деструкторов, то, опять-таки, согласно стандарта C++ (10.3 Virtual functions)

> 6 Even though destructors are not inherited, a destructor in a derived
>   class overrides a base class destructor declared virtual; see 12.4 and
>   12.5.

То есть если деструктор в базовом классе объявлен со спецификатором `virtual`, то деструктор в производном классе переопределяет деструктор базового класса, то есть ведет себя как виртуальная функция.

Comment: `присутствие  ... делает код более ясным` — как по мне, этой цели следует ключевое слово `override`. `virtual` же сбивает с толку, не позволяя определить, переопределение это или же введение нового виртуального метода.

Comment: @Arhad Привычки вырабатывались в те времена, когда `override` и близко не было :)

Comment: @Arhad Контекстно-зависимое ключевое слово override появилось только в стандарте C++ 2011. До этого его не было.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, при чем здесь первая цитата. Она говорит, что если определение виртуальной функции сделано вне класса, то указывать там слово `virtual` запрещается. То есть к переопределению виртуальных функций в производных классах она никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @AnT Я не увидел в этой цитате то, что вы написали. Я увидел в ней то, что я написал "То есть спецификатор функции virtual обязан присутствовать только в первоначальном объявлении функции". Возможно, что эту цитату следует переписать в стандарте так. чтобы она не вызывала разночтений.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Не вижу никаких разночтений. Первоначальное объявление функции `Base::foo` - это ее объявление в классе `Base`. Только там разрешается указывать спецификатор `virtual`. Если пользователь захочет сделать еще и определение функции `Base::foo` за пределами класса, то там указывать `virtual` нельзя. Именно об этом и говорит приведенная вам цитата. А функция `Derived::foo` - это совершенно самостоятельная функция, для которой объявление `Base::foo` никаким боком не является "первоначальным". Это во-первых.

Comment: Во-вторых, вы что ли намекаете на толкование, в рамках которого стандарт якобы запрещает указывать `virtual` в `Derived::foo`, если оно было указано в `Base::foo`??? Такого токования нет и быть не может, ибо всем прекрасно известно, что такого запрета в С++ нет и никогда не было. В С++ у вас всегда была и есть легальная возможность указать избыточный спецификатор `virtual` в классе-наследнике. Если же вы подразумеваете какое-то еще толкование - то поясните его, ибо совершено не ясно, к чему это тут.

Comment: @AnT Я написал довольно ясно, что "То есть спецификатор функции virtual обязан присутствовать только в первоначальном объявлении функции". Вы можете опустить этот спецификатор в объявлении функции в производном классе.  Эта цитата не говорит ничего про определения или другие объявления. Она говорит о том, когда этот спецификатор обязателен.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Нет, не верно. Ваша первая цитата призвана носить *ограничителный/запретительный* смысл: "shall be used only". А именно: "Спецификатор `virtual` разрешается использовать *только* в изначальном объявлении нестатической функции-члена класса (и больше нигде)". Никакого отношения к функциям производного класса эта цитата не имеет. Эта цитата просто говорит, в каких контекстах разрешается применять спецификатор `virtual`.

Comment: @AnT Вот только сейчас вы правильно трактуете фразу. Однако в главе 10.3 не исключается использование virtual для функций, объявленных в производном классе.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Именно так я ее трактую с самого начала. И никто не спорит с тем, что использование `virtual` в производном классе является разрешенным (и опциональным). В моих комментариях речь идет лишь о том, что ваша первая цитата к вопросу производных классов никакого отношения не имеет. Вы, похоже, по-прежнему не улавливаете, что с точки зрения этой цитаты объявление `Base::foo` не является "изначальным" для `Derived::foo`. С точки зрения этой цитаты `Base::foo` не имеет никакого отношения к `Derived::foo` вообще.

Comment: @AnT Почему же не имеет? Она затрагивает концепцию, что "даны примеры, где по мнению авторов виртуальных деструкторов в производных классах является, видимо, хорошим тоном.". Я описал сначала, когда слово Virtual вообще необходимо.

Comment: С точки зрения голой грамматики языка вы можете написать `virtual static int foo() { return 42; }` для функции `foo` даже не являющейся членом класса. Так вот назначение процитированного вами 7.1.2/2 - сказать, что так делать нельзя. Ни больше, ни меньше. Это не более чем *грамматическое ограничение*, даже не знающее, что по сути значит `virtual` и не имеющее никакого отношения к наследованию или перекрытию виртуальных функций.

Comment: @AnT Вы ходите по кругу. Цитата говорит, когда спецификатор virtual обязан присутствовать. И больше ничего. Это не значит, что он не может присутствовать в производных классах. Просто он избыточен. Возникает вопрос: следует ли его использовать в производных классах? И я ответил на этот вопрос. Я указал 1) когда он необходим, 2) и когда его можно избыточно использовать для документирования класса.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Нет, не верно. Еще раз: данная цитата говорит, когда  спецификатор `virtual` обязан **отсутствовать**, а не присутствовать. И еще раз, даю точный смысл этого пункта стандарта: "несмотря на то, что грамматика языка допускает спецификатор `virtual` в *любом* объявлении, его разрешается указывать *только* в первом объявлении нестатического метода класса". Все.

Comment: Зачем вы мне повторяете, что "это не значит, что он не может присутствовать в производных классах" - мне не ясно. Я с этим никогда не спорил. Я лишь говорю, что цитата в 7.1.2/2 никакого отношения ни к каким производным классам не имеет вообще. 7.1.2/2 - это чисто грамматический пункт стандарта. Ни о каких "производных классах" 7.1.2/2 не знает и не хочет знать. Никакого отношения к переопределению виртуальных функций в производных классах 7.1.2/2 не имеет.

Comment: @AnT Я указал, когда именно спецификатор обязателен. В остальных случаях этот спецификатор избыточен. Точка. Далее я указал, что хоть он и избыточен в других случаях, но он может использоваться для документирования определения класса. На мой взгляд все логично и ясно.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Прекрасно. Чтобы сделать функцию виртуальной, *требуется* указать `virtual` в базовом классе. Об этом говорит именно 10.3. Указывать `virtual` в классе-наследнике не обязательно. Об этом тоже говорит 10.3. Вот и все. А 7.1.2 говорит только о том, что нельзя писать `virtual double x = 13;` и `virtual static int foo()`. Потому я и заметил, что к сути вопроса 7.1.2 отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 1):

Он автоматически будет виртуальным.

Достаточно пометить функцию-член как виртуальную в базовом классе; такой она будет и в производном.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    virtual void f() const { cout << "B\n"; }
    virtual ~B() { cout << "~B\n"; }
};

class C: public B
{
public:
    void f() const { cout << "C\n"; }
    ~C() { cout << "~C\n"; }
};

class D: public C
{
public:
    void f() const { cout << "D\n"; }
    ~D() { cout << "~D\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    B*b = new D;
    b->f();
    delete b;
}
```

Хотя `D::f()` не имеет слова `virtual`, это ничего не меняет...

Код тут: http://ideone.com/mqG4NW

Comment: Может быть это как-то связано с разрушением объекта по указателю на базовый класс?

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Т.о. "виртуальность" деструктора производного класса необязательна, главное - его наличие, верно?

Comment: Что именно? Объявление виртуальности в производном классе? Оно не обязательно, но лично я всегда его использую - просто для того, чтоб самому случайно не забыть, что эта функция - виртуальная. Гляньте на код - то, что деструктор не объявлен как виртуальный в производном классе, не делает его не виртуальным...

Comment: Объявление виртуальности не важно. Наличие - ну уберите в коде `~C` - все равно `~D`будет вызван (или уберите `~D` - `~C` будет вызван), просто отсутствующий деструктор будет сгенерирован компилятором. Опять же, как виртуальный.

Comment: > ну уберите в коде ~C - все равно ~Dбудет вызван - я только что убедился в обратном - http://ideone.com/4xjKtT

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что если вы какой-то деструктор не напишете, он все равно будет иметь место и будет вызываться.

Comment: У вас все равно вызывается **сгенерированный** `~D`, просто он ничего не выводит :) Я для того и воткнул три класса в иерархию, чтоб показать вызовы несмотря на "невыводимость"...

Comment: >  несмотря на "невыводимость"
Можно про это чуть подробнее? А в целом - понял, спасибо Вам.

Comment: Да я имею в виду, что сгенерированный деструктор - пустой, ничего не выводит, так что фиг его вызов на экране отследишь :)

Comment: Плюс уже Vlad from Moscow поставил :), но огромное Вам спасибо за развернутые объяснения!

Answer (score 1):

Как и все остальные переопределенные виртуальные функции, его надо помечать как **`override`**, `virtual` при этом писать не нужно.

```
struct Derived : Base {
  ~Derived() override;
};
```

Comment: Следует отметить, что `override` работает с C++ 11